# aws load balancer for different instances and same ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have two EC2 instances running websites on port 80.

Is it possible to use/configure 1 load balancer for these two instance/services? 
When I try to add a listener on existing load balancer, it says "You may not have duplicate load balancer ports defined".

Or should I use 2 load balancer, one for each instance?

Comment: What type of load balancer exactly? It sounds like you need an Application Load Balancer.

Comment: It appears your existing load balancer is already listening on port 80. Add a new load balancer to listen on port 80 and add your EC2 instances to it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Load Balancers define **listeners** by the incoming traffic ports they listen on. When a client connection hits the load balancer on a certain port (i.e. 443 or 80), a **listener** forwards that request to a **[target group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html)**. To have a listener on port 80 forward connections to multiple instances all you need to do is create a target group containing those instances.
[image]

The most common approach for public-facing websites is to use something like [Amazon Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) to create TLS certificates for the website. Then they load that certificate into their load balancer and listen on port 443 (typical port for HTTPS) and pass the connections over HTTP (typically port 80) on to the target groups. This is commonly referred to as TLS or SSL Termination.

---

If the instances are hosting **different** websites but you want to route based on the hostname submitted (i.e. example.com and example1.com) then you can create a separate target group for each website and use an Application Load Balancer (ALB) to route based on the hostname supplied by the requester.

This can be done after you have created the ALB by going to the ALB subconsole and modifying the listener rules similar to the screenshots below.

[image: edit listener rules]
[image: rules]

To serve a separate certificate for each host you'll also need to add those certificates to the listener as I wrote in my [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancer-sni/) outlining the feature.

[image: animated gif of certificate changing]

Comment: To be more precise, the 2 instances are loading different websites so I want the load balancer to route based on the hostname supplied by the requester. I created 2 separate target group for each instance/website, but how to set the Application Load Balancer (ALB) to automatically route to the correct instance? It seems I can forward the HTTPS : 443 listener to a single target group only?

Comment: I've updated the existing answer with a lot more info - I think the issue you're facing is that many of the options to edit the listener rules are not available in the console creation wizard - you have to create the ALB and then edit the rules to route to multiple target groups (and add multiple TLS certs). If this has answered your question please don't forget to check this as "answered".